# Change start of week from Sun to Mon with PHP Relative Time Formats

Tags: php

I have a function in PHP using strtotime() and relative time formats which should return the first day of the week but it is automatically set to Sunday instead of Monday. Is there any way to change this?

```
function start_of_week() {
    $monday = strtotime('monday this week');    
    return date("Y-m-d", $monday);
}
```

For example today is Sunday 11th and the above function is returning tomorrows date when that would be Monday *next* week

Answer (score 1):

I think this can works for you .

```
function start_of_week()
{
    $monday = strtotime('monday this week');

    $today_day = date('D');

    if($today_day != "Mon")
        $start_of_week = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last monday"));
    else
        $start_of_week = date("Y-m-d", $monday);

    return $start_of_week ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, the argument startFrom is initialized as Monday if you like you may change this , but i think that you may need to call this function later using default starting day..
instead call start_of_week(2) to set Tuesday as the first day in the week, as a result you need now to use start_of_week(7)

```
function start_of_week($startFrom=1) {
    $dateTime =new DateTime(); // today
    $diff = ($startFrom - $dateTime->format('N'));
    if ($diff > 0) { $diff -= 7; }
    $dateTime->modify("$diff days");
    return $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
    }
    echo start_of_week(7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the next and everything is alright:

```
$monday1 = strtotime("monday this week");
$monday2 = strtotime("next monday");
$monday3 = strtotime("monday next week");    
echo '<br>'.date("Y-m-d", $monday1); // output : 2014-05-12
echo '<br>'.date("Y-m-d", $monday2); // output : 2014-05-12
echo '<br>'.date("Y-m-d", $monday3); // output : 2014-05-19
```

So, where is your problem ??

Comment: nice very clean and self explanatory